# Highlight textarea border with jquery for a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I highlight the border of a textarea as so to call the user attention towards something that's missing there/not correct? I want it to flash for a certain period of time. Can this be done with css3? Thank you very much! (hint, it goes on when the user presses the **L** key).

```
<textarea></textarea>





if(e.keyCode == 13)
executeGlowBorder();
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/glowing-blue-input-highlights/ similar effect (but I only want it to extend for a certain period of time)

Comment: @Satpal I know, that's not the point to which I want to refer

Comment: Use that in conjunction with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your request, there's multiple way to achieve what you're trying to. One of them would be to use a mix of `addClass`, `removeClass` and `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` for the temporary highlight. Look at the this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFuae/) and let me know if this is what you were trying to achieve.

```
$('textarea').change(function () {
    if (!isValidEmailAddress($(this).val())) {
        $(this)
            .fadeIn(750).addClass('glow')
            .fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750)
            .fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750)
            .fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750)
            .fadeOut(750).fadeIn(750);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('glow');
    }
});
```

---

You asked for a solution with CSS3, but your question tags included JQuery; I'm guessing JQuery can be included in the suggested solution. There's also a way to do it without JQuery, but its much less prettier.